# Why this code has no effect when run through Task Scheduler?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-8, operating-system

I created a simple program with the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ShowWindow(FindWindow(L"Shell_TrayWnd",L""), SW_HIDE);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, it will just find the taskbar window and hide it.

I set this program on the task scheduler to run right after the user logs on the Windows 8. After setting it up, rebooted the system and logged in, the taskbar is still visible. The task scheduler says the program was run successfully.

However, when I try to run this program by double clicking it, the taskbar becomes hidden.

Any ideas what could be the reason why this code won't take effect when run through task scheduler?

Comment: Check the `FindWindow` call for success.

Comment: Btw the second parameter of `ShowWindow()` is treated in some peculiar fashion the first time the function is called - MSDN has all the details.

Comment: @chris I did that suggestion but it still has no effect. See my comment to David's answer.

Comment: Why do you want to hide the taskbar. Kind of makes Windows unusable.

Comment: @David It's for a custom application that requires removing the taskbar. Kind of a kiosk.

Comment: If you can remove it, user can put it back. Why don't you use true kiosk mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities that I can see:

1. The process when executed from the task scheduler is run in a different desktop. This is a common issue with scheduled tasks.
2. Your process runs before the shell has shown the taskbar window.

It's plausible that you are affected by both.

For item 1 you should switch to using HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run to trigger your process.

For item 2 you'd need your program to wait until the window was shown, before hiding it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried your first suggestion and it did hide the taskbar; however it took many seconds before the program was triggered. So I'm attempting to implement your second suggestion. My try: 

    #include <windows.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
 HWND h;
 do{
  Sleep(200);
  h = FindWindow(L"Shell_TrayWnd",L"");
 }while(h == NULL);
 ShowWindow(h, SW_HIDE);
 return 0;
    }

This code however has no effect when tried to run on task scheduler. Is there still a way to run it on startup, but not having many seconds delay?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to format the code in a comment though, so it looks gibberish. Maybe someone can edit it? :(

Comment: I think it's highly likely that the problem with the task is that the code runs in a different desktop, even a different session. That's hard to surmount. No amount of waiting will help.

Comment: I also suspect that is the case. So if the task scheduler runs it on a different session, what could be the possible way to find the taskbar window handle?

Comment: There isn't one. Sessions are isolated.

Comment: I finally figured it out. Turns out that the taskbar was indeed hidden but somehow it appears again. So I modified the code to monitor when the taskbar appears, and hide it again. I just let the program do this for about a minute to be safe. The result is acceptable enough. Thanks for your ideas, it led me to a solution.